# ¿Cómo puedo borrar los botones generados automáticamente?

Tags: android

tengo una función que me genera botones automáticamente dependiendo de una respuesta que le llega de una consulta SQL. Lo que ocurre, es que si ejecuto dicha función más de una vez, se generan el doble de botones necesarios (los que ya estaban creados, más los nuevos).

El código es este:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nUsuariosSalas.size(); i++){
                        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                        //Asignamos propiedades de layout al boton
                        button.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        //Asignamos el texto al btn
                        button.setText("Telefono de "+nUsuariosSalas.get(i));
                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                String trucada = "tel:+34 " + usuchat.getTelefono();  // prefix d'Espanya + el número de telèfon del contacte
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                intent.setData((Uri.parse(trucada)));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        //Añadimos el boton al listView
                        lstChats.addView(button);
                    }
```

Hay alguna manera para eliminar los botones generados anteriormente antes de generar los nuevos?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,se me ocurre esta posible idea:

Podría declarar una variable global (tendría que evaluar en que parte de su código) de tipo bandera, una vez se ejecute el ciclo for, cambiar el estado de dicha variable bandera. Para que esto funcione debería preguntar el estado de la bandera antes de ingresar al ciclo for. Debería ser algo mas o menos así:

```
//variable global, debe determinar donde ponerla de tal forma que esta sea declarada solo cuando se cargue su aplicación
boolean bandera = true;

if(bandera){
    for (int i = 0; i < nUsuariosSalas.size(); i++){
                    bandera = false;//cambio de estado
                    Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                    //Asignamos propiedades de layout al boton
                    button.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    //Asignamos el texto al btn
                    button.setText("Telefono de "+nUsuariosSalas.get(i));
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            String trucada = "tel:+34 " + usuchat.getTelefono();  // prefix d'Espanya + el número de telèfon del contacte
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                            intent.setData((Uri.parse(trucada)));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    //Añadimos el boton al listView
                    lstChats.addView(button);
    }    
}
```

Espero mi respuesta le sea de utilidad.

Comment: Si lo hago de esta manera, cómo podría después volver a crear los nuevos botones?

Comment: No, solo se generan por una única vez. Para el caso en que se deban crear cada vez que se ejecuta la función ya que en cada ejecución existe información nueva, las alternativas que veo son 2: Crear los botones en primera instancia y la siguiente vez que se ejecute solo reemplazar los campos de los botones, esta opción solo funciona si en cada ejecución de la función existe la misma cantidad de botones (misma estructura siempre). La opción 2 es en caso de que la cantidad de botones a crear varié en cada ejecución, en cuyo caso habría que vaciar los botones de la lista para poner los nuevos.

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar los botones agregados dinamicamente a una vista, puedes usar `removeAllViews()` para remover todos los hijos de la vista, en este caso serìa:

```
lstChats.removeAllViews();
```

esto lo puedes realizar antes de realizar el bucle para añadir los botones.

Comment: He probado esta orden, pero no hay ninguna diferencia. Se repiten igualmente. Hay alguna otra orden para borrar?